# How can i add divider to my drop down list (spinner)?

Tags: java, android, xml, spinner, android-spinner

[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYNLp.png)

[after click - i'd like to add such blue line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKZFL.png)

I would like to add divider to my drop down list.

I used solutions which I found on stackoverflow but they didn't work.

This is my xml code for in xml fragment

```
<Spinner
     android:id="@+id/spinner1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:spinnerMode="dialog"
     android:background="@drawable/spinner">

</Spinner>
```

This is spinner.xml. It is define boarder, shape and image of("click-button")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <layer-list>

            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <padding
                        android:left="0dp"
                        android:top="0dp"
                        android:right="0dp"
                        android:bottom="1.5dp"
                        />

                    <gradient android:startColor="@color/white" android:endColor="@color/white" android:angle="270" />
                    <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="@color/colorPrimary2" />
                    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

                <item android:gravity="center|right" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_spinner_drop_down"/>



        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: A divider where?

Comment: I added photos,

Answer (score 2):

> This works only for spinnerMode="dropdown"... for dialog mode the divider has to be [added during runtime via an adapter](https://demonuts.com/android-spinner-divider/) (the referenced sample is also using dropdown but after implementing it and changing the mode to dialog, the divider is still being displayed).

Just try adding this to your `styles.xml` file inside the `values` resource directory:

```xml
    <style name="SpinnerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:divider">#0000ff</item>
        <item name="android:dividerHeight">0.5dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>
    </style>
```

And then, you can either add an extra child node to the `style` tag that's already there in that file (that will apply the style to all spinners):

```xml
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- ... -->
        <!-- ... some existing lines -->

        <!-- ... new line to add:-->
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerStyle</item>
    </style>
```

Or... you can just add that style to your specific Spinner tag in your fragment XML  (that will apply the style to only this spinner):

```xml
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner"
        android:theme="@style/SpinnerTheme">
    </Spinner>
```